# Car chase on the lunar surface

Tags: story-identification, space

I'm trying to identify a scene I saw on TV a year or two back. All I can remember is that it had a chase across the surface of the Moon, using vehicles that looked like stretched versions of the Apollo lunar rover with six wheels instead of four. I think the good guys were trying to reach a particular place and the bad guys were trying to stop them. There might have been gunfire involved. That's all I remember - I don't even know if it was a film or an episode of a TV series.

Comment: I'm baffled why anyone would close this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This could well be *[Ad Astra](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2935510/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_5)*, a science fiction film from 2019 starring Brad Pitt. When Pitt's character, Roy McBride, reaches the Moon, he is chased by "Moon Pirates" in lunar rover-type vehicles. The rovers had 4 wheels as normal though, I think, but were stretched and carried armaments. You can see a clip of the action [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stOVFXuyyWQ).

[image: Still from "Ad Astra" showing the lunar rover chase]

Comment: Yeah, that's the one! I see the question has been closed as it didn't include enough detail - well, that's as much as I could remember but it was clearly enough for you to pin it down!